# Replace or tighten a screwless hinge

Tags: doors, hinges

The door seems to tilt backwards which makes door closing hard and I'm thinking it's because of this old top hinge with the screw sort of exposed.

I'd heard that tightening the hinge could help but I have no idea how would I do this with this kind of hinge.

I also have no idea how would I replace the hinge.

Is it even possible ?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Maybe a few more pictures would be helpful.

Comment: @Jack Sure, I'll add them in 15 to 30 mins what should i shoot?

Comment: did they tile or wall over the flange part?  How can there not be screws?

Comment: @Jack I think the screws go into the wood, I'm not sure if there is a flange part. I've managed to find a photo of a similar hinge (the top one) https://www.sarka.rs/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/90280041.jpg I was also confused on how there were no screws.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a pintle and gudgeon hinge. Usually the pintle is on the wall and the gudgeon is on the door, so that the gudgeon cup does not fill up with debris.

Search term "gudgeon", or "pintle", or "pintle and gudgeon hinge".

It is designed to come apart by lifting the door straight up. Then the individual parts (the "gudgeon" and the "pintle") can be unscrewed from their pilot holes.

In your case, you would remove the door, screw the top fitting further into the wall, and replace the door.

This will be complicated by whatever caused the fitting to start from the wall in the first place, which probably will require removing the fitting and repairing the hole.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see there you'd maybe lift the door off the hinges, thread each part of the hinge in a bit, and reinstall the door.

However, if the hinge has pulled out this is unlikely to resolve the issue. It'll pull out again. Might be time to replace what appears to be some positively ancient hardware.